# How to create an alternate method of authentication in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create an alternate method of authentication in CakePHP 3 besides the classic username/password method since I'm planning to let users to authenticate with a Facebook account.
My strategy is as follows:

When the user clicks "Sign up or Login" buttons their FB information is going to be retrieved and created/updated in my database. After that the users shall pass and access the system.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to create an additional method of authentication that only would required the user FB token to be registered in my Users database.

I've checked the CakePHP 3 documentation about [Authentication Handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) but it's not very clear.

If someone could please help me out with this issue, I would appreciate a lot!

This is my Javascript code:

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,permissions', function (response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.first_name + ' id: ' + response.id);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '!';
        $.post('/users/register/' + response.id + '/' + response.first_name + '/' + response.last_name + '/' + response.email, function (data, status) {});
    });
```

Comment: Why you not try with some of plugins, like  https://packagist.org/packages/akkaweb/cakephp-facebook , https://packagist.org/packages/admad/cakephp-hybridauth etc

Comment: Go with Nick Baker's CakePHP Facebook plugin (  http://www.webtechnick.com/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more ). It is easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.smarttutorials.net/login-with-google-oauth-2-using-php-and-mysql/

The strategy is that on login - if the user is not in your table, redirect them to the auth2 login page for facebook.

Once the user allows your app, request their info and manually log them in.

```
 $this->Auth->setUser ( $user );  //$user is an array
```